# iOS presenting view controller animated as 'Push' (right-left animation)

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7, custom-transition

Currently, I have a view controller presenting other view controller. What I'm trying to do is to recreate the default animation used when pushing a view controller.

My current approach is:

`FirstViewController`:

```
@IBAction private func push(sender: AnyObject) {
    let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController")

    let transition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = 0.5
    transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight

    view.window?.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: kCATransition)

    presentViewController(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

`SecondViewController`:

```
@IBAction private func pop(sender: AnyObject) {

    let transition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = 0.5
    transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft

    view.window?.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: kCATransition)

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
}
```

It is almost working, but I have a weird behaviour, I'm having a kind of black screen/flash when transitioning between view controllers. I already tried changing `window.backgroundColor` but it is not fixing the issue.

Thanks in advance 0_0...

Comment: why don't you use the default transition?

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is merely that what you're doing is not how to customize the animation for a present/dismiss transition. Apple has provided you with a clear, well-establish, official way to do that, and what you're doing is not it. You need to give your presented view controller a `transitioningDelegate` along with implementations of `animationControllerForPresentedController:` and `animationControllerForDismissedController:`, and implement the UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning protocol, possibly along with a custom UIPresentationController subclass.